# Remove empty arrays from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got an array I use in a `FormValidator` class, but at some point I end up with an array sort of like the following. But I would like to remove all empty arrays from that array so that in my validation it's not gonna check for values inside the empty array, which is inefficient.

Is there a function to remove empty arrays from multidimensional arrays?

I know about `array_filter()` but that seems to only work with array element values.

```
array(2)
{
  ["recaptcha_response_field"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["terms"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this- This will remove empty arrays as well inside array!

```
$array['recaptcha_response_field'] = array(
   'name'=>'name1',
   'email'=>'email1',
   'empty'=>''
);
$array['terms'] = array(
   'name'=>'name2',
   'email'=>'email2',
   'empty'=>''
);

$array['terms2'] = array();


$array= array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));

print_r($array);

OUTPUT-Array
(
    [recaptcha_response_field] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1
            [email] => email1
        )

    [terms] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2
            [email] => email2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(array('foo','bar'), array('hi',''), array('',''), array('','hello')); 
$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));
print_r($array);
```

will show :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
>   hi ) [3] => Array ( [1] => hello ) )

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `foreach` with `array_filter` and `count` as the call-back function.

```
foreach($arr as $k=>&$arr)
{
    array_filter($arr,'count');
}
print_r($arr);
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/137419)

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to remove an element from array. To identify the null elements fire recursive loop. hope it will work !